# With crtl-p can I open a file outside the current tree?

Tags: vim, vi

In looking to have functionality that can match my textmate friends for opening files with quick regex capability I found ctrl-p - https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim

It builds, indexes and then works off the directory tree you are currently in.

Is there any way to open a file such as `~/aa/x.x` using ctrp-p when I am currently in the `~/bb/` tree, even though `x.x` is within `~/aa/` ?

Comment: Not ctrl-p but you can use glob to search through an entire tree for files. Something like `**/x.x` Drawback is that this isn't an indexed list. Depending on the tree size, it could take a while.

Comment: user454038 yes that wasn't clear and I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to use a custom command for listing files. The README shows `find` as an example:

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'find %s -type f'        " MacOSX/Linux
```

Try:

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'find %s ~/aa -type f'
```

For example, with:

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'find /etc %s -type f'
```

Looking for `vimrc`, ctrlp lists these files:

```
> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/65-wqy-microhei.conf
> /home/muru/.vim/bundle/airline/LICENSE
> /home/muru/.vim/bundle/ctrlp/doc/tags
> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/65-khmer.conf
> /etc/vim/vimrc.local
> /etc/vim/vimrc.tiny
> /home/muru/.vim/.vimrc.swp
> /etc/vim/gvimrc
> /etc/vim/vimrc
> /home/muru/.vim/vimrc
```